# xmlhttpresponse create a textnode from object with numbered nodes

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

in my project i have an xmlhttprequest object like this:

[image: response node]

now in my script i need to create a textnode with parameters of response object like this

```
if (typeof(response.serps) === 'undefined' || response.serps === null) {
        tse3 = document.createTextNode("NO DATA");
    } else {
        tse3 = document.createTextNode(response.serps.1.headline+"<br>"+response.serps.1.url);
    }
```

but the editor make error  in response.serps.1 (when i write 1 number).
How can i take data from this node with numbers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the bracket notation to access properties which are numbers:

```
response.serps[1].headline
```